# Regex Patterns in Laravel Routes for Complex URL Structures

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes

I want to define variables with the brand token in the URL. My brand token here is /brand/.

My URL: http://localhost:8000/tools/main_category/supplier/sub-category1/sub-category2/brand/brandName

I just want to access subcategories and brand in URL. My first approach like below.

```
Route::get('/{main_category}/{supplier}/{model?}/{sub_category?}/{brand?}', [StoreController::class, 'show'])->name('store.supplier.category')
        ->where('subcategory', '.*[^\/brand]+.*')
        ->where('brand', '[^\/brand]+');
```

But this is returns me a `subcategory1/subcategory2/brand/brandName` as subcategory.

Then I tried some different regexes. I tried `.*?(?=\/brand\/)` for the subcategories and `(?<=\/brand\/).*?(?=\/|$)` for the brand. This is works well on regex101.com but it not works in Laravel Routes and returns 404 error.

---

By reading some code and doing some attempts, I reached the following results.

Firstly, I realised that my regexes were compiled by Symfony Route.

Then I change the where statements like below

```
        ->where('sub_category', '.*[^\/brand]')
        ->where('brand', '.*');
```

This change resulted in the following compiled regex:

`^/tool/(?P<main_category>[^/]++)/(?P<supplier>[^/]++)(?:/(?P<model>[^/]++)(?:/(?P<sub_category>(.*[^\/brand]))(?:/(?P<brand>(?<=[\/brand\/]).*))?)?)?$`

However, I've not yet achieved the desired result.

Now I can separate the brand and subcategories, but I can't separate the brand without code redundancy in Controller or somewhere else.

I mean; I can get the brand as /brand/brandName, but I only want to get the brand name.

Example of a compiled regex: https://regex101.com/r/0ZWU6I/latest

p.s: the regex101 not shows groups well but this is works right in Laravel

Comment: try something like so: `\/(?P<sub_category1>[^\/]+)\/(?P<sub_category2>[^\/]+)(?=\/brand\/brandName)` see at https://regex101.com/r/yIpIaA/latest. also - i am no php expert, but consider using an URL parser.

Comment: I already use Laravel's route engine to parse URLs. Your approach is acceptable, but it's not what I want.